# Saving game progress data in python

Tags: python-3.x, saving-data

I am saving the game data in another file which kinda looks like this:

```
def progress1():
    s1 = 0
    return s1

def progress2():
    s2 = 0
    return s2

def progress3():
    s3 = 0
    return s3
```

In the main file I import those functions in and the player can change the 
s(1,2,3) value when he gets to a certain chapter in the story. But if I would close the program and reopen it the data would be lost as the s(1,2,3) would be set back to 0. I would prefer to not use MySQL things as it seems a bit complicated.

How can I save this progress to a file?

Comment: Are you saving progress by writing out a python module? Why not use a structured data format, like json or yaml, or pickle a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, but I find you post  a little unclear. Are you using python source file to save your progress? Comments on the other questions indicate you should use a text file. Please edit your question, add a little more source to help us understand.

Comment: I cant understand how the formatting of the code works on this site. Can someone just explain it? And I am saving it in a python module